# HTTP 404 error in a servlet in Eclipse with Apache tomcat v7

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Following is my jsp code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="connection.*" %> 
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %> 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>VIEW REPORTS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div align="center"><b>View Reports</b></div>
    <form action="GetRole" method="get">
    <p>Enter user id:
    <input type="text" name="userid"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"><br>
    </form>
    Choose the type of report:
    <script type="text/javascript" src="list.js"></script>
    <select name="first1" id="firstselect" onchange="first()">

        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="NEFT">NEFT REPORTS</option>
        <option value="LOAN">LOAN REPORTS</option>
        <option value="TRAN">TRANSACTION REPORTS</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript"></script> 


    </body>
    </html>
```

Following is my servlet:

```
      package all_packages;
      import connection.*;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.sql.*;

      import javax.servlet.ServletException;
      //import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
      import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
      import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
      import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
      public class GetRole extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            Connection con=getConnection.getConnectionBuilder();
            String userid=request.getParameter("userid");
            System.out.println(" "+userid);
            PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select role_id from users where role_id=?");
            pstmt.setString(1,"userid");
            ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(" "+rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection unsuccessful");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      }
```

Following is my `web.xml`:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Final_Bank</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
      <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>GetRole</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>GetRole</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>GetRole</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/GetRole</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

Please let me know why it is throwing 404 error. I searched the web for quite some time to get a proper resolution but no solution is working for me. I have used Apache Tomcat Server in Eclipse.

Comment: When does the error occur? Which URL? After submitting the form?

Comment: @andih, Yes after submitting the form. Aftrer submitting, url is coming: `http://localhost:8080/Final_Bank/GetRole?userid=wcw`

Comment: Can you please update your the `web.xml` in your post to represent your current local version.

Comment: Have you checked the console if there are any errors during startup of the web application? Have you tried to access the GetRole resource via tools like curl `curl -v http://localhost:8080/Final_Bank/GetRole?userid=...` ? Curl allows you to see the request/response and also avoids caching issues. In eclipse it may helps if you clean up the module work directory. That can be found in the "Server View".

Comment: @andih, Thanks for your valuable input. Finally I figured out to add servlet url pattern and servlet class as shown in the below given answer. My problem was in url pattern. But now I am getting another error as my servlet is throwing "Nullpointer exception" after providing the input in the line of "preparedStatement".

Answer (score 0):

The servlet is in the package `all_packages` so the mapping in `web.xml` file should be:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>GetRole</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>all_packages.GetRole</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Now coming to the `404` issue, if the jsp name is say `sample.jsp` and the application context name is `myapp` then the URL that you need to access is:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/sample.jsp
```

assuming your tomcat is running on port `8080`.

Comment: If that's the reason I would expect a `ClassNotFoundException` during startup of the WebContainer / WebApplication / Tomcat.

Comment: Still after this modification, I am getting the 404 error.